# Procedure and Requirement for connecting Azure ADFS with existing ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, azure, adfs

A bit of introduction from my end about the Application:

We are having ASP.NET web application with SQL server membership provider for user authentcation. In addition to this our application supports SSO   from client's application(for ex: siteminder).

One of our client is changing their SSO infrastructure from siteminder to Azure(Active Directory Federation service) as I am pretty new to Azure ADFS so I am not aware of what all things are required and the procedure to connect to our ASP.NET web Application. Though I have certain queries too:

- will there be any infrastructure change from our end? means do we need ADFS server at our end to communicate to the client's ADFS server OR is it possible that we connect directly to client's ADFS server from our ASP.NET web application?
- will there be any software upgradation required? currently we are using Visual Studio 2013(update 2), .NET Framework 4.5

Note: Application needs form authentication for internal users

Comment: This is not a suitable question for SO. It is too broad and opinion based. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as Azure ADFS.

There is Azure AD and ADFS. They are completely different products.

ADFS only authenticates against AD. It cannot authenticate against a SQL server membership provider. If you need this, use identityserver to authenticate against the DB and federate this with ADFS.

You can either federate your ADFS with theirs or connect your application to their ADFS. Both are valid.

To do this, your application needs to support WS-Federation (WIF), SAML 2.0 or OpenID Connect (ADFS 4.0).